# Custom metadata in AS3/Flex?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, metadata

How to create and to work with custom metadata in ActionScript3/Flex?

Comment: Really good questions & answers. Could someone please list some examples of how this would be useful though? Thanks!

Comment: @bigp Some architectural frameworks use custom metadata (Parsley, Swiz, for example)

Comment: Will these custom metadata work in Flash CS* IDEs as well when compiling?

Comment: @bigp it should. You deal with classes and objects like in other IDEs, so reflection should work

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is two general directions to deal with metadata in ActionScript in Flex:

1. Dealing in runtime using reflection (or introspection in terms of Adobe). You can find documentation [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=usingas_8.html). There are several third-party libraries which provides more convenient reflection API such as [as3-commons-reflect](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-reflect/) or [reflection API in Parsley](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/).
2. Using Flex Compiler Extensions which was introduced since Flex 4 SDK revision 8165 (see [details](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-18718)). See also [the corresponding discussion](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/459515?tstart=0) and [official documentation](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+3+Compiler+Design).

Answer (score 15):

To create metadata, just use square bracket syntax in your class definition:

```
[ClassAttr]
public class ClassWithMetadata {
    [AttributeNoArgs]
    public var data:Object;

    [AttributeWithArgs(arg="value)]
    public var prop:Object;
}
```

Call `describeType(ClassWithMetadata)` to get xml description of your class. Metadata will be there, you can parse it and process as you like.
To prevent compiler from stripping your metadata, add compiler argument `-keep-as3-metadata Attribute` for each attribute name you using. This can be done in library settings or in each project that uses metadata.

Comment: Thanks for example! If i could accept more than 1 answer...:)

Comment: Is this unique to the Flex compiler (mxmlc), or will the metadata be retained in the Flash Professional compiler as well?