# Flex Metadata Compiler Extension in FlashDevelop tutorial

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-construction, metadata

I've been googling around for the past 2 hours looking for some simple instructions on how to add my own custom metadata tag in as3 with no success. I'm starting to think that I'm probably not searching for the correct terms.

### The Problem

Ultimately, what I want to do is add a custom metadata on a function that takes a function as a parameter and makes sure that the given function has the correct parameters.

I.e. I have the following function:

```
public function testCallback(callback:Function):void
{
    callback("test");
}
```

and I want to get a compiler error when I call it like this:

```
public function doNothing():void
{
    // doing nothing
}

public function someRandomFunction():void
    // ...
    testCallback(doNothing);
}
```

The way I'm thinking of doing this is by having this metadata:

```
[Callback(paramName="callback",callbackParams="string")]
public function testCallback(callback:Function):void
{
    callback("test");
}
```

The extension would run *during compilation* and, if the function passed does not contain the correct parameters, **a compile-time error will be thrown**. I *THINK* by using flex2.compiler.util.ThreadLocalToolkit.logError(path, line, errorMessage); I can accomplish this.

### The Search

I've been googling for a couple of hours now and couldn't find a simple tutorial that could get me started. I found some SDK bug reports ([SDK-18718](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-18718), [SDK-26041](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-26041)), an [unfinished forum post](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/459515?tstart=0), a tutorial (?) on [how to add a custom metadata in FlexBuilder](http://ravigeek.wordpress.com/2011/07/10/digging-into-custom-metadata-tag-in-flex-and-actionscript/) (I'm using FlashDevelop), a [not-so-useful answer in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5729427/2644) and many many more dead ends.

### The Help

So far, as far as I could understand, I will use Java to create the extension and then, using a compiler command, I'll add it into my project. However, I don't know what do I need to get started.

**My two main questions are:**
A) What do I need to create the extension in Java? (do I need Flex Builder? Eclipse? what libraries do I need in my classpath?)
B) Once I have compiled this into something (a swc?), how do I include this in FlashDevelop in my AS3 Project?

Thanks in advance!

### Update

I've been able to create a Java project in eclipse, add the Flex libraries, implement the IMxmlcExtension interface and compile the project into a jar with the correct MANIFEST file. Unfortunately, adding the extra -extension=MyTest.jar in FlashDevelop, did nothing.

In case it is useful, the resulting command line for the compiler was

> mxmlc -load-config+=obj\MyProject.xml -debug=true -incremental=true
>   -swf-version=10 -extension=flex_test.jar -o obj\MyProject634846490611881374

### Update 2

[Timofei Davydik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592882/timofei-davydik) helped me narrow down the problem. It seems that FlashDevelop is the main problem. Creating an extension and compiling it in command line works. I started a thread in FlashDeveloper's forums. In case you're interested, the thread is: [-extension compiler option](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?uid=9313&f=9&t=9985&start=0)

### Update 3

[Pilippe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27219/philippe) is correct, it seems that the problem comes from the fact that FlashDevelop uses [Flex Compiler SHell (fcsh)](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_32.html). I am now looking into how can I switch compilers.

Comment: Assume you could write extension and generate some code, then what would it be? Do you want to throw some custom exception? But you it will throw exception in case of incorrect number of parameters of incorrect parameters type without any additional code. Could you please just describe the idea of handling it? Thanks

Comment: @TimofeiDavydik Updated my question with my goals.

Comment: Can you check that it works when using the Flex Compiler SHell (FCSH) which is what FlashDevelop uses internally for optimal incremental compilation.

Comment: @Philippe I tried to compile using fcsh but the extension didn't work. So I think you are right, the problem is fcsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to make meta-data tags work in Action Script**

[Timofei Davydik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592882/timofei-davydik)'s wrote a quick and simple tutorial in his blog to answer my question, named [Flex compiler mxmlc extensions. Forcing compiler language](http://tim-davydik.blogspot.com/2012/09/flex-compiler-mxmlc-extensions-forcing.html), and helped me a bunch to track down what is the problem (which is why I'm giving him the bounty). In his post, he is using Flash Builder and not FlashDevelop, which brings us to the answer of the next question:

**How to program them using Flash Develop**

Unfortunately, as [Phillipe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27219/philippe) pointed out, for AS3 projects, FlashDevelop uses the Flex Compiler SHell (FCSH), which doesn't support meta-data. Since FlashDevelop is open-source, I'll try (and probably fail) to switch the compiler for testing purposes. For anybody else interested in this, I think this forum post is a good start: [[ GIFT ] Try new AS3 compiler (ASC 2.0) in flashDevelop 4.x](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=9918)

Answer (score 2):

Really interesting question. I've done some research. Yes, we can write mxmlc extensions and add some custom functionality. But processing custom metadata is really complicated, and much time is needed debug and explore flex compiler sources. I've created a post in my blog about extensions, you can check it:

http://tim-davydik.blogspot.com/2012/09/flex-compiler-mxmlc-extensions-forcing.html

Comment: Thanks for the blog post. I created an Eclipse project and added exactly what you written. I then added the line in the MANIFEST file and finally went to FlashDevelop and added the line -extension=MyTest.jar in my compiler. I compiled my project but nothing happened. :/

Comment: @pek Ok. Let's try to find out what's the problem. Could you share your jar somehow?

Comment: @pek, What compiler are you using? It could be a problem if you're using built-in FlashDevelop compiler. Could you try pointing at original one inside SDK folder? I'm using IntelliJ IDEA for my flex projects and it's also doesn't work until I point at the original mxmlc at settings.

Comment: I tried all three: FlashDevelop compiler, the newest 4.x SDK, and even compiled one from SVN. None of them worked :/

Comment: @pek and what do you mean by "nothing happened"? Did it compiled without "hello world" message? Or didn't it compiled at all with error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17405/discussion-between-timofei-davydik-and-pek)