# Metadata for Exceptions thrown by a class

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

Flash builder lets me insert metadata for events fired by a class, example:

```
[Event("myEvent", "flash.events.Event")]
public class MyClass() {

}
```

Is there any way to do the same for Exceptions?

Currently I have checked [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf680e1-7ffe.html), and can't see it documented. Perhaps it's not even worthwhile, what are your thoughts.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Note that all exceptions are runtime exceptions. There are no checked exceptions in AS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways to create your own metadata; and add that into your app at compile time.  Use the [keep-as3-metadata compiler argument](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html).

It will be up to you to write code to do something with it at runtime; or to build IDE extensions to make use of the code while writing the code.

To access such metadata at runtime, you'll need to perform some type of introspection.  [Here are some docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=usingas_8.html) and [another StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729294/custom-metadata-in-as3-flex) about this.

Many Flex Frameworks make use of custom metadata.