# Cheap structures in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Generally low-level languages support `struct`s, just what I want to hackishly define in AS3. We can do this on C#, but why do it? Because 3d positions are very common and it's boring to create an object for each 3d position just because you can't get a immutable structure in other languages freely, unless you don't want to declare a bunch of locals yourself.

[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@hydroper/structcmp)

```
struct Vec3f {
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double z;
}

class Test {
    static void Main() {
        Vec3f cam1 = new Vec3f();
        Vec3f cam2 = cam1;
        cam1.x = 10;
        System.Console.WriteLine(cam1.x == cam2.x); // false
    }
}
```

As you can see, `Vec3f` is a immutable value type. But in JS, Lua, AS3 or whatever we usually can't have these kinds of immutable structures. Yep, we use objects, which are always garbage-collected AFAIK.

In AS3 I wanted to be able to meta-mark a class as **immutable**, but I don't see how if that's not supported anywhere. There's no existing ABC-level tool, so how?

```
[Immut] // or [Immutable]
class Vec3f {
    var x: Number
    var y: Number
    var z: Number
}

var a: Location = new Location
var b: Location = a
a.x = 10
a.y === b.x // `true`, but should be *********`false`*********
            // for `Vec3f`.
```

Comment: Plain data types (**String**, **Boolean**, **int**, **uint**, **Number**) are immutable and are passed as a value, all other data types subclass the **Object** class and are mutable, which means you pass any instance as a reference (pointer if you speak C/C++) to it. There's no avoiding it. The common practice here is to define classes with a custom **clone(...)** method that returns a (shallow or deep upon your needs) copy of a given instance.

Comment: @Organis Immutability isn't my goal at all. I wanna immutability in the sense `Vec3f` objects violate the default object rule (like `Vec3f` were a primitive), so mostly a `[Immut]` meta-data could allow me to violate default mutability. I wanna make `Vec3f` work exactly as a native, low-level and non-object C `struct`. What I want is that `Vec3f` violates at all many object concepts from ECMAScript and expands everywhere like it were a local box, container.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you aim at. Let me say it again: there's no avoiding it. AS3 just does not have such an option or metadata.

Comment: @Organis It's possible to violate `Vec3f` semantics in ABC-level, so it's just missing a tool for that. The ABC tool can expand it to 1) ABC locals and variables, 2) box it to an object (whose constructor is still flagged as _Vec3f_, making `is` and `as` operators work) where it's _\*irregularly\*_ used 3) and maybe some extra actions. Extra checking can ensure the struct-like class is appropriate for inheritance.

Comment: Weeeell, you can command the compiler to keep the custom metadata while compiling to ABC: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729294/custom-metadata-in-as3-flex Then you indeed need some ABC editor tool to tweak the result so it respects the metadata. As a proof of concept, well, if you say it is possible. Otherwise, I believe, **clone(...)** way is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)**

> Generally low-level languages support **structs**, just what I want to hackish-ly define in **AS3**. 
> We can do this on **C#**...

With regards to your AS3 versus C# results...

```
// C#   :   System.Console.WriteLine(cam1.x == cam2.x); // gives false.
// AS3  :   trace(a.y === b.x); // gives "true", but should be ******** "false".
```

The AS3 results are because you previously used: `var b: Location = a` which effectively makes `b == a`. So now whenever `a` changes then `b` changes equally too.

**Solution**:

To create a hack-ish version of a **struct**, you'll simply have to **use a class**. To make each class unique, just use the **new** keyword.

```
import Vec3f; //import the class (if external AS file)

//# then use "new" keyword to make variables as unique instance of class
var cam1 :Vec3f = new Vec3f();
var cam2 :Vec3f = new Vec3f();

//# check start values (where... vec3f.x == 5 )
trace(" 01 :: cam1.x == " + (cam1.x) ); //gives 5
trace(" 01 :: cam2.x == " + (cam2.x) ); //gives 5

//# update values
cam1.x = 10;
trace("cam1.x == cam2.x ??? result : " + (cam1.x == cam2.x) ); //gives false

//# value checks v2 (results after update)
trace(" 02 :: cam1.x == " + (cam1.x) ); //gives 10
trace(" 02 :: cam2.x == " + (cam2.x) ); //gives 5
```

Even Java does not have `struct` objects so the [typical solution (example)](https://coderanch.com/t/528008/java/structs-Java-called-structs) is to *"just use classes"*.

In  AS3 others have solved this by creating their own **point3D** implementation like in [**this example**](https://github.com/bgstaal/as3-tools/blob/master/src/net/bgstaal/perspectiveprojection/Point3d.as).

**(2)**

> But why do it (use a `struct`)? Because 3D positions are very common and it's boring to create an object for each 3D position.

Maybe investigate the [**Vector3D**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Vector3D.html) API. It's easy to setup (the `w` is an optional value, eg: angle or velocity).

```
var some_vec3f = new Vector3D(x:Number = 0., y:Number = 0., z:Number = 0., w:Number = 0.);
```

Also read:

- AS3 [**`Matrix3D`**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix3D.html) API guide.
- AS3 [*`PerspectiveProjection`*](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/PerspectiveProjection.html) API guide.
- [Performing complex 3D transformations](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSA340940C-A537-450c-8069-A4A052A98CAA.html) with AS3.

Hopefully this might be enough to help you achieve a data-container for your 3D points.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Truly I know how to use classes and define my own constructors, or maybe even builders. But there's an inefficiency in constructing true objects (when using `new Class` or just `{ p: 'v' ] }, [ array ]`), or mayben't at all. The inefficiency is the fact the instance object will go to heap and be garbage-collected in a hidden mark-sweep algorithm, while within a `struct` I won't have these issues, it'll simply be performant as a primitive value.

Comment: But I still guess the performance difference between value-type `struct`s and objects (`class`es, usually) is minor, if many persons out there say so...